# Long numbers in PostgreSQL and bitwise operations

Tags: postgresql, bitwise-operators, long-integer, bigint

There's a django application using PostgreSQL DB.
Our task is to collect and store MSSQL Server permissions (their count is about 120). It implemented as a long number where each bit is 1 permission.
Thus we need to store a very long number in our PostgreSQL but its MAX numeric value is 64 bits. That's why we store is as a string now. 
Application creates a SQL query like:

```
SELECT "mssql_ace"."id", .... "mssql_ace"."permissions",

FROM "mssql_ace"

LEFT OUTER JOIN ... ON ...
...
WHERE (.... AND ("mssql_ace"."permissions" & 1) = 1)

ORDER BY ... ;
```

The problem now is on WHERE part. We need bitwise operations, it's a way to filter data by permissions that works in the whole app except this. We can't use bitwise operations with string.

We'd tried casting in PostgreSQL:

```
1. (CAST("mssql_ace"."permissions" AS BIGINT) & 1)

2. "mssql_ace"."permissions"::BIGINT & 1
```

And other things:

```
3. DECIMAL also doesn't support bitwise
```

We have an idea to divide this big number on two parts. But it needs a lot of work to change inside app. Any other ideas? The main thing we can't change is usage of bitwise operations.

Thank you.

Comment: could you share some sample? I don't get you keep it in `bit(120)::text` or `power(2,120)::text` or how?..

Comment: For example:

"mssql_ace"."permissions" == "633902673727753278450355404800" 

and inside query it's: (.... AND "633902673727753278450355404800" & 1) = 1)

it fails because string & integer. 

We'd tried: 
(CAST("633902673727753278450355404800" AS BIGINT) & 1)
or
"633902673727753278450355404800"::BIGINT & 1 
- both fail because of number length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to integrate that in django, but the logical PostgreSQL data type for this would be [`bit varying`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-bit.html). It allows you to efficiently store long bit strings.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-postgres-pebble/0.0.6 
- contains BitStringField that works with bit varying in django. 
Thanks a lot!